# Web Scraping Get Text to CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to Python - WebScraping, and I want to extract text from website and export to csv files,
but i got a problem when check the csv file,
When i run this code (with print) :

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import csv 

URL = "https://intanseafood.com/demersal-fish"
r = requests.get(URL) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib') 

quotes=[]
table = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'archive-product'}) 

for row in table.findAll('div', 
                        attrs = {'class':'product-h2'}): 
    quote = {} 
    quote['product'] = print(row.get_text())
    quotes.append(quote)
```

Results:

```
                                Fish Goldband Snapper Natural Cut






                                Fish Grouper Portion






                                Fish Ruby Snaper Natural Cut






                                Fish Croaker






                                Fish Grouper WGGS






                                Fish Pinjalo Snapper Natural Cut






                                Fish Parrotfish WGGS






                                Fish Snapper One Cut
```

But when i change it to this code (export to csv) :

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import csv 

URL = "https://intanseafood.com/demersal-fish"
r = requests.get(URL) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib') 

quotes=[]

table = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'archive-product'}) 

for row in table.findAll('div', 
                        attrs = {'class':'product-h2'}): 
    quote = {} 
    quote['product'] = row.get_text()
    quotes.append(quote) 

filename = 'demersal.csv'
with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f: 
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,['product']) 
    w.writeheader() 
    for quote in quotes: 
        w.writerow(quote)
```

File csv created, but nothing inside except the header. Kindly anybody help me to resolve this, Thanks in advance

Comment: i ran your code and the output is as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of whitespace in your first output which means there are tabs/spaces/new lines in the string. Doing a little digging showed it was a newline and tabs. Remove them, for example:

```
text = row.get_text()
quote['product'] = text.replace("\t", "").replace("\n","")
```